# Integrating logistic regression with CA to simulate land cover after prediction

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, geostatistics

I have used logistic regression in R to predict the probability of change in 3 types of land cover, the map of probability is generated for my case study.

[image: This is the probability map for 30 years prediction]

I do not know how to use the probability maps to simulate the actual map of my case study, I was thinking to integrate CA and my probability map. Does anybody have an idea about simulating the actual map by using the generated probability map derived from logistic regression?